# explanation of List<String> how it is being used in the code

Tags: java, arrays, list

```
public static void main(String a[]){
        String[] strArr = {"JAVA", "C++", "PERL", "STRUTS", "PLAY"};
        List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(strArr);
        System.out.println("Created List Size: "+strList.size());
        System.out.println(strList);
```

I was looking for the explanation of the code

```
String[] strArr = {"JAVA", "C++", "PERL", "STRUTS", "PLAY"};
```

this line means that we are declaring a variable `strArr` of string type  and in the array we are declaring 5 variables is that correct

Then I am unable to clearly understand second line

```
List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(strArr);
```

is `strList` an object of `List<String>`?

Comment: What part about that line do you not understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the below code you are converting your String array to a fixed size list.

`List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(strArr);`

While converting an Array to a List. You can perform all operation of List to your newly created fixed size list. Exmaple Sorting a List as below.

`Collection.sort(strList);`

But with the above code you cannot add element into your list. While adding element in list it will throw you an exception. Sample code as below.

```
String[] strArr = {"JAVA", "C++", "PERL", "STRUTS", "PLAY"};
List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(strArr);
strList.add("Spring"); // This line will throw exception
System.out.println("Created List Size: "+strList.size());
System.out.println(strList);
```

If you want to add element to your list you have to convert your String Array to List as below.

`List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(strArr));`

Hope this will help you to understand it

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList()` is a static util for java. It creates a `List` copying the values from your `array of strings` (or any kind of primitive/object).

You can check the documentation on [docs.oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/%E2%80%A6). The benefit of a `List` is that the size is variable, so you can add or remove elements (in short, it has no fixed size) while an `array` has a fixed size. This is true for `List`(`Mutable list` by default) unless you use an `Immutable List` which has a fixed size like an array.

Comment: In the doc for Arrays.asList() --  *Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.*  There is no copying; this list is not variable-sized.

Comment: In general, using Arrays.asList() is because what you have is an array and what you need is a List, possibly to satisfy subsequent code (which we don't have in the OP's question so we cannot guess why a list is needed). The sort of construction the OP shows is a handy way to initialize a fixed List; it is more concise than writing a sequence of calls on the list's 'add' method.

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList(T... arr)` is a static method, sort of a utility, that takes an array as input and returns a `List<T>` backed by the input array. So, yes `strList` is a `List`.

To answer your question in the comments about "backed by":

From the Javadoc: "Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.)".

So, the list is backed by the array in the sense that all changes made to the contents of the list will be reflected in the array. Example:

```
    String[] a = new String[] {"1", "2", "3"};

    List<String> l = Arrays.asList(a);
    l.set(0, "0");

    assert a[0] == "0";
```

Comment: Arrays.asList() is a static util for java. It creates a List copying the values from your array of strings (or any kind of primitive/object). You can check the documentation here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...) . The benefit of a List is that the size is variable, so you can add or remove elements (in short, it has no fixed size) while an array has a fixed size. This is true for List (mutable list by default) unless you use an Immutable List which has a fixed size like an array.

Comment: The comment is wrong. The answer is right. I'm upvoting this answer because it's the only answer that is correct and to the point.

Comment: In the answer what does "backed by input array" mean